# Get rid of horizontal scrollbar CSS

Tags: horizontal-scrolling

This is driving me crazy. Horizontal bar keeps showing up

This is the site:
http://www.injinji.com/shop/
Thanks anyone!!
Jorge

Comment: We’re not site-debugging elves! What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `dropdown.css` on line 76, where `ul.dropdown ul` is defined as having a `width` of `2500px`.

I discovered this by the process of deleting elements until the scrollbar disappeared :)